# Why is there a comma added after toString() on a List?

Tags: java

I have this type of code
        List l = new ArrayList();

```
    l.add(" ;foo;bar;end");
    l.add(" ;more;foo;bar");

    String output = l.toString();

    System.out.println(output);
```

The output is

```
[ ;foo;bar;end
,  ;more;foo;bar
]
```

I expect

```
 ;foo;bar;end
;more;foo;bar
```

How do I get rid of the comma and

Comment: Well, `toString()` for collections is defined to have brackets and commas. If you don't want them, you need to iterate and print the way you need it.

Comment: But I have a huge number of strings and if I roll my own the performance is horrible.

Comment: If so, perhaps you are using the `+` operator to build your string instead of using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: when you add elements to arrayList are separeted with comma,you should iterat it

Comment: @user2472565, the `toString` method does iterates under the hoods so it itself is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma is used to separate your two strings in array, to remove in string representation of your array, you should do something like:

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer()
for (String element : l){
    stringBuffer.append(element).append("\n");
}
String result = stringBuffer.toString();
```

Comment: `StringBuffer` is not recommended unless you need thread-safe string building. `StringBuilder` is better in a single-threaded implementation.

Comment: Agree, forget who is who )))

Answer (score 1):

use like this fix the problem

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner (System.in);

        List l = new ArrayList();

        l.add(" ;foo;bar;end");
        l.add(" ;more;foo;bar");

            for (Object object : l) {
                System.out.println(object);

            }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

In th Doc JAVA. `toString` is a Method inherited from class `java.util.AbstractCollection`

> public String toString()
>
> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string
>   representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the
>   order they are returned by its iterator, **enclosed in square brackets
>   ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma
>   and space)**. Elements are converted to strings as by
>   String.valueOf(Object).